# Export class and namespace from the same file

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a code with the following structure:

```
export class Component {
  constructor(options: Component.Options) {}
}

export namespace Component {
  export interface Options {
    // some values here...
  }
}
```

Then it is used like this:

```
import {Component} from './component'

const options: Component.Options = {};
new Component(options);
```

The issue happens, when `Options` definition is growing too much and we would like to extract namespace with interfaces into a separate file:

**./component/interfaces.ts**

```
export namespace Component {
  export interface Options {
    // some values here...
  }
}
```

**./component/index.ts**

```
export * from './interfaces';

export class Component {
  constructor(options: Component.Options) {}
}
```

When this separation happens, the code becomes not valid, Typescript returns an error

```
 index.ts:3:16 - error TS2702: 'Component' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here.

 const options: Component.Options = {};
                ~~~~~~~~~
```

Is there a way to fix it without changing the exported names? We cannot do this, because these interfaces are already consumed by customers and we cannot change the names within a minor version bump.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to merge definitions is to define them with the same name in the same scope (global, module (including all augmentations), or namespace) to give a single symbol.  Once you have two distinct symbols, you cannot merge them by any means, including trying to export them under the same name.  For implementation reasons, a class has the additional restriction that namespaces can only merge with it if they are defined later in the same file.  So you'll have to define the `Component` namespace in `index.ts` and copy individual members from `interfaces.ts`; unfortunately, there is no way to use a wildcard.  For example, you could write in `index.ts`:

```
import { Component as InterfacesComponent } from './interfaces';

export class Component {
  constructor(options: Component.Options) {}
}

export namespace Component {
  export import Options = InterfacesComponent.Options;
}
```

Or you could omit the namespace layer from `interfaces.ts` and update the import accordingly if you find that less confusing.